# Netbeans hotkey to show overloaded version(s) of a Java method?

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, editor, overloading

At the moment, when write code and get into a method that has many overloaded versions, `Ctrl-Space` will display the overloaded list as snapshot #1 below.

[image]

After I choose one version, I want to switch to another overloaded version but I don't know what hotkey to **reshow** the overloaded list, as shown in snapshot #2. Currently I have to delete the arguments and hit `Ctrl-Space` again which is quite tiring to me.

What is the hotkey to reshow that list then?

[image]

Comment: Just a termonology issue, I think you meant "overloaded" (method with same names but different arguments) instead of "overriden" (methods of a superclass reimplemented in a suclass)

Comment: Yeah you are rite! Thanks @SJuan76. I'll update my OP

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to do what you want. I took a look at the shortcuts configuration and didn't find anything.

`Ctrl + Space` is related to code completion. Hitting `Ctrl + Z` again can work if you selected the method with less parameters.

Maybe the best alternative is to hit `Ctrl + Z` after the wrong completion. It will restore the state just before the wrong selection. Then hit `Ctrl + Space` again.